# Conditional OperationProcessor in NSwag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, nswag

I try to add conditionally an `OperationProcessor` in NSwag. For example, the `DefaultApiValueOperationProcessor` should only be added/enabled when we are in a development environment  (`env.IsDevelopment`)

Unfortunately I can't retrieve `IHostingEnvironment` in `ConfigureServices`, and also I can't get the Swagger's `OperationProcessors` on `Configure`, see code example at the comment lines:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerDocument(s =>
        {
            // can't get IHostingEnvironment here? (for env.IsDevelopment())

            s.OperationProcessors.Add(new DefaultApiValueOperationProcessor("version", "1"));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // can't get Swagger's OperationProcessors here?

        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3(o =>
        {
            o.DocExpansion = "list";
            o.DocumentTitle = "My API";
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the web host environment from `ConfigureServices`, simply add a `WebHostEnvironment` property to the `Startup` class and set it from the constructor:

```
public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        WebHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (WebHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I also put the `Configuration` property in this example because a lot of programs need it anyway.

Please note that the type is `IWebHostEnvironment` and not `IWebHostingEnvironment` because the latter has been deprecated.

Regarding your second question (how to access the operation processor from `Configure`), could you please shed a light on your intentions? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! The second question would be another way to fix this, but one good solution is enough :)